# internalization set language redirect view. how to redirect to the same page?

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have a form that currently redirects to the index page :

```
    {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <form name="setLang{{ lang.1 }}" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/"/>
            <input type="image" name="language" src="/static/img/{{ lang.0 }}.png" alt="{{ lang.1 }}" value="{{ lang.0 }}"/>
            <a href="/" onclick="document.setLang{{ lang.1 }}.submit();return false;"></a>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

How can I make it redirect to the same page ?

Comment: Tried using `action=""`?

Comment: @kroolik /i18n/setlang/ does all the magic that changes the language in the website. value="/" is the value of where it should redirect.

Comment: Have you tried returning `redirect(request.REQUEST['next'])` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)) in the `setlang` view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a way to get the current path, but plain - without the leading language code. Given that Django will redirect user to the correct URL automatically.

I wrote a simple function that strips current language from a given path. It's based on how `django.core.urlresolvers.resolve` deals with language codes in paths, so should be pretty solid:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language
import re

def strip_lang(path):
    pattern = '^(/%s)/' % get_language()
    match = re.search(pattern, path)
    if match is None:
        return path
    return path[match.end(1):]
```

You can use it in your view to pass a language-less path to your template:

```
def your_view(request):
    next = strip_lang(request.path)
    return render(request,  "form.html", {'next': next})
```

and then use it in the template:

```
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ next }}"/>
```

---

Alternatively you can easily [make the function into a template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) and use it in your template directly:

```
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.path|strip_lang }}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.path }}"/>
```

Comment: I've already tried that. request.path returns the current path, while I need a new one. For example if I was in /en/categories and I switched to russian it would still return /en/categories, because its the path im coming from and what I need is /ru/categories.

Comment: Write your own template tag to build an url for new language then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood the problem, but I believe you can use something like this.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^blablabla/(?P<language>\w{2})/categories/$', views.my_view),
```

And than extend the page based on `language`

Answer (score -2):

This is simpler

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language

def strip_lang(value):
    lang = get_language()
    return '/%s' % value.lstrip('/%s/' % lang)
```

Comment: If `lang = 'en'` and `value = '/en/nearest-store/'` then the return value will be `'/arest-store/'. Don't pass more than one character to `lstrip`  :)